# Dynamically added view has no style function React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, view

I'm using carousel in my app (taken from here https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel)

I'm trying to add a view each time a user swipe to the right.

That is the code I'm using:

```
export default class AllRand extends Component
{ 

  constructor(props)
  {    
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      myArr: ['Page numebr: ', 'Page numebr: ']
    };
  } 

  _onPageSwitchAnimateEnd()
  {
    this.state.myArr.push('Page numebr: ')
    this.setState({
        myArr: this.state.myArr
    })
  }

  render()
  {    
    let Arr = this.state.myArr.map((text, index) => {
      return <View key={ index } style={ styles.shit1 }><Text>asdasd { index }</Text></View>                            
    })      

    return (
      <Carousel animate={false} hideIndicators={false} onPageChange={() => this._onPressOut()}>
        { Arr }
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}
```

I succeed adding a View but it is not with the style, text 'Page number: ' and index...

[image]

[image]

[image: Why doesn't it have the style and content as the previous ones?]

**UPDATE:**

changed my code but still doesn't work...

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Carousel from 'react-native-carousel';
import FactsApiFetcher from './facts-api-handler/facts-api-fetcher'

export default class AllRand extends Component
{ 

  constructor(props)
  {    
    const InitialnumberOfPages = 2;

    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      numberOfPages: InitialnumberOfPages,
      Pages: this._setInitialPages(InitialnumberOfPages)
    };
  } 

  _onPageSwitchAnimateEnd()
  {    
    let updatedNumberOfPages = this.state.numberOfPages + 1;
    let newArr = this._addPage(updatedNumberOfPages);

    this.setState({        
        numberOfPages: updatedNumberOfPages,        
        Pages: newArr
    });
  }

  render()
  {   
    return (
      <Carousel animate={false} hideIndicators={false} onPageChange={() => this._onPageSwitchAnimateEnd()}>
        { this.state.Pages }
      </Carousel>
    );
  }

  _setInitialPages(numberOfPages)
  {
    let tempArr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
    {
      tempArr.push(<View key={ i } style={ styles.shit1 }><FactsApiFetcher/></View>);
    }   

    return tempArr;
  }

  _addPage(updatedNumberOfPages)
  {    
    return this.state.Pages.concat([<View key={ updatedNumberOfPages - 1 } style={ styles.shit1 }><FactsApiFetcher/></View>]);    
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shit1: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFF00'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AllRand', () => AllRand);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's causing your bug but `this.state.myArr.push('Page numebr: ')` will mutate your original state object. And the following `setState` can end up writing over your mutation.  Best practice is to use a function that creates a new array and then use the new array in the `setState`

Comment: did you mean something like this? (still not working...)

  _onPageSwitchAnimateEnd()
  {
    this.setState({
        myArr: this._createNewPage()
    })
  }

  _createNewPage()
  {
    let temp = this.state.myArr;
    temp.push('blabla');
    return temp;
  }

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I would try _onPageSwitchAnimateEnd() { this.setState((prevState) => ({ myArr: prevState.myArr.concat([ 'blabla' ]) })) }  Array.prototype.concat takes two arrays, concatenates them and returns a new array (the original isn't modified).  In your example, temp would simply be a reference to the original array so pushing would modify the original.  But I'm not really sure that that's the problem

Comment: Do you want to throw your project up on Github?  Maybe people can play around with it and get it working

Comment: Does Bitbucket also work for you? (I want to share this project only with you and I saw all repositories in github must be public). What's your username?

Comment: Hey, looks like you solved your issue. I just created an example repo that takes the code you provided above and it seemed like everything is working: https://github.com/gwmccull/rncarouselexample  The only difference is that I think you said you had a custom event function and I didn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

So eventually the problem was because there is a bug in the Carousel library I used ( https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel). From some reason, the callback function that adds the pages is messing up the pages array (don't know why...).]

When I tried using another Carousel library the function worked.

My only advice I can give following this experience is that when you think you tried all the possibilities in order the fix your bug, try changing the libraries you are using (to another same functionality library).

Comment: Good advice on trying other libraries.  I've found the quality of libraries can be variable, especially if you're doing something that isn't exactly like the author's use case.  Glad you got it working!